# Showing that a third degree polynomial with roots in terms of roots of fourth degree polynomial has rational coefficients

Tags: galois-theory

Been sitting with this question from for a whole bunch of hours now. I'm studying for an exam so I don't want to be stuck for too long, however much I dig endlessly pondering.

Let $f(t)$ be a separable polynomial in $\Bbb Q[t]$ with zeros $\alpha_i,i=1,\dots,4$. Let
\begin{align*}
\beta_1=\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_3\alpha_4\\
\beta_2=\alpha_1\alpha_3+\alpha_2\alpha_4\\
\beta_3=\alpha_1\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_3
\end{align*}
and $g(t)=(t-\beta_1)(t-\beta_2)(t-\beta_3)$. Show that $g(t)\in \Bbb Q[t]$.

So, since the coefficients of $g$ are
\begin{align*}
\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3\\
\beta_1\beta_2+\beta_1\beta_3+\beta_2\beta_3\\
\beta_1\beta_2\beta_3
\end{align*}
I just want to show that they're rational. A common approach is to try to express them in terms of
\begin{align*}
s_1&=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4\\
s_2&=\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_1\alpha_3+\alpha_1\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_3\alpha_4\\
s_3&=\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_1\alpha_3\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4\\
s_4&=\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4
\end{align*}
which I know are rational 'cause they're the coefficients of $f$. But this is where I don't get any further. I know that if the coefficients of $g(t)$ are symmetric polynomials in the roots, then they can be expressed in terms of $s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4$ but f.ex. $\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3$ for sure ain't symmetric, since with $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 4 & 3\end{pmatrix}$ we get the term $\alpha_2\alpha_4$ which isn't a term of $\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3$.

What do you think? Am I not thinking enough?

Comment: Are you sure that your definition of $\beta_2$ is correct? I think it should be $\alpha_1\alpha_3+\alpha_2\alpha_4$.

Comment: Haha, I was sure beginning to think there was a typo. I did the corresponding change of $\beta_1$ but that didn't yield much. I'll try yours too and report back.

Comment: @AlexFok It worked, is there any other way of fixing the typo up?

Comment: I made the correction for you.

Comment: You don’t need to show that the $\beta_j$ are individually invariant under any permutation of the $\alpha_i$, but just that $\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3$ is, for instance. And the others you quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to show that the triple $\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3\}$ is invariant under all permutations of the roots $\{\alpha_i\}$, since the fixed field of $\Bbb Q(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_4)$ under the permutation group $S_4$ is the field of the elementary symmetric functions in the $\{\alpha_i\}$, which are the coefficients of the polynomial, assumed to be in $\Bbb Q$.

So it only remains to show that every simple exchange of two of the $\alpha_i$ leaves the set $\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3\}$ unchanged. For instance, $\alpha_1\leftrightarrow\alpha_2$ leaves $\beta_1$ fixed, but interchanges $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$. You’ll find the same result for any other simple exchange. So all is well.